# Are commercial placeholder domain names not blocked here?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, blacklist

I’ve just suggested an edit to [a question which used xyz.com as a placeholder domain name](https://serverfault.com/q/601763). Lots of people are unfamiliar with [RFC 2606](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2606), and therefore use domain names other than `example{.com|.org|.net}` as placeholders. Such domain names are [blocked from use on Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/208963) according to a [status-completed](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/status-completed) [policy discussion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/186529), so why can they still be used here on Server Fault?

Comment: Related: [What information should I include or obfuscate in my posts?](http://meta.serverfault.com/q/963/126632)

Comment: I keep shoveling back the tide by editing such questions when I find them, but it does get tiresome.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

They should be blacklisted here. But the blacklists are site-specific, not network-wide. They're also not something moderators can touch, so someone from Stack Exchange would have to add them.

Comment: Blocking stuff like http://www.mysite.com may block some legitimate questions (specifically, ones where the OP cites a tutorial written by someone who has never read RFC 2606). Whether or not we want such questions is a matter for a different discussion though.

Comment: Hmm. I can't remember ever seeing a question that would have been blocked in that rather narrow scenario. Do you have one handy?

Comment: not off the top of my head, but I know I've seen tutorials and config examples use mysite.com (it seems to be a popular one). Personally I have no problem with blacklisting these domains though - ***PROFESSIONALS*** should be familiar with RFC 2606.